# Extract value using JSON Path from array

Tags: java, json, jsonpath

I have Json like this below

```
{"pd":"{\"e\":{\"h\":{\"ak\":\"120\",\"at\":\"app\"},\"b\":[{\"ts\":1319549658547,\"tz\":-400,\"s\":\"StartUpScreen\",\"et\":8,\"ev\":\"sessionStart\",\"si\":\"19477682-de55-414f-82c9-19bec331dc33\",\"tt\":{\"day\":\"Tuesday\"}},{\"ts\":132,\"tz\":-400,\"s\":\"StartUpScreen\",\"et\":3,\"ev\":\"AutomaticFeedRefresh\",\"si\":\"19477682-de55-414f-82c9-19bec331dc33\",\"tt\":{}},{\"ts\":131,\"tz\":-400,\"s\":\"MainScreen\",\"et\":3,\"ev\":\"MainScreen Event\",\"si\":\"19477682-de55-414f-82c9-19bec331dc33\",\"tt\":{}}],\"tt\":{\"OSV\":\"7.10\"}}}","serverPayload":{"httpHeaders":{"x-bluecoat-via":["35D3468EFF4D5F18"],"content-type":["application\/x-www-form-urlencoded"]},"senderIp":["101.100.000.100"]}}
```

I just need the values of `ak`, `b [ts,si and tt[day]]` and `senderIp`.
Now I have 2 questions, how do I extract all 'ts' attributes in 'b' and 'senderIp'. I have used the below code for ak, ts and si. I am not sure how I get 'tt', also while I run this code I get an exception like below

```
    String pd = JsonPath.read(jsonString, "$.pd");
    String ak = JsonPath.read(pd, "$e.h.ak");
    String ak = JsonPath.read(pd, "$e.h.b[0]");
//    String b = JsonPath.read(pd,"$.e.b[0][0]");
//    String b = JsonPath.read(pd,"$.e.b[0][5]");
    System.out.println("value of ak: "+ak);
```

Exception in thread "main"
`java.lang.ClassCastException: net.minidev.json.JSONObject cannot be cast to java.lang.String`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.e.h.b[0]` looks like a JavaScript object (with fields including "ts" and "tz"), not a string.  So it's reasonable for your JSON parser to treat it as a JSONObject rather than a string.  Probably you need to drill down to `$.e.h.b[0].ts` or whatever field you're interested in.  Something like this:

```
long ts = JsonPath.read(pd, "$e.h.b[0].ts");
```

I'm assuming it's your second `String ak =` line which causes the exception.  I'm having trouble understanding your other question about the "ts" attributes.  Maybe you could format the JSON string for easier reading?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Comment: @ Hew Wolff
TO make it simple, I want to extract values of ts,si, tt and 'senderIp' values

Comment: "ts" is an integer in the JSON, right?  So you should try to get it as an integer type.  If you were trying to get it as a string, that would explain the exception.  I edited my answer to give a bit more detail on that.

Comment: thanks for your help, i ve got the answer... to get ts i should traverse to the object with array like b[0].ts and convert the value to string or use tostring() method

Comment: Excellent.  If you care to accept my answer by clicking on the check mark, it will give me a warm feeling.  :-)

Comment: i have a similar issue, can you help me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35251927/jsonpath-no-value-for-json-path-id-exception-path-id-is-being-applied-to