# jsonpath: No value for JSON path: $.id, exception: Path 'id' is being applied to an array. Arrays can not have attributes

Tags: java, json, spring, mocking, mockmvc

i tried to read the content of the json with jsonPath and i get an error.

Here the junit test method:

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/path")
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id", is(1)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.name", is("NAME")))
                .andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString();
```

here is what the request return me:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"NAME","....}, ....}]
```

i got this error:

```
No value for JSON path: $.id, exception: Path 'id' is being applied to an array. Arrays can not have attributes.
```

can someone helps me.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The response returns a JSON array and using `"$.id"` you try to access the `id` property of that array. This - as the error message tells you - is not possible.

Test the `id` and `name` property on the first element of the array instead:

```
.andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].id", is(1)))
.andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].name", is("NAME")))
```